# Unable to pass an object to exported javascript module on nodejs / expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, scope, openapi-generator

I am not able to pass an object to function exported from another module. Here's how the story goes.

I am exporting a function from module **TagService.js**

**file: TagService.js**

```
addTag = ({tag}) => {
  //some activity
}

module.exports = { addTag, //other functions}
```

Invoking the function from module **ServiceHandler.js**

**file: ServiceHandler.js**

```
const Controller = require('./Controller');
const service = require('../services/TagService');
const addTag = async (request, response) => {
  await Controller.handleRequest(request, response, service.addTag);
};
```

Here's how the controller is structured in **Controller.js**

**file: Controller.js**

```
static async handleRequest(request, response, serviceOperation) {
  //some activity    
  const serviceResponse = await serviceOperation(this.collectRequestParams(request));
  //some more activity...
}

static collectRequestParams(request) {
  //some activity
  return requestParams;
}
```

Now, in the **Controller**, ***requestParams*** is returned successfully. But when the call steps into addTag function at **TagService**, the object ***tag*** is not passed!

A little bit more background. This is code generated from [openapi-generator](https://github.com/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli) for the nodejs-express-server stub.

Here's the openapi.yaml template for tag service.

```
/samyojya-tag:
    post:
      operationId: addTag
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Tag'
      responses:
        "201":
          content:
...
schemas:
  Tag:
      example:
        name: name
        id: 1
        type: type
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
        category:
          type: string
      type: object
      xml:
        name: Tag
```

Using **node 12.16.2** and **express 4.16.1**

Comment: that means in `TagService.js` you cant access in your function `addTag` the object?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. @Ifaruki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you destructure the object with `({...})`

In your case you can only access the property `tag` from your passed object, if your passed object dont have a property called named `tag`, its undefined.

You should change this `({tag})` to this `(tag)` to have the full access of your passed object

```js
var obj = {
   test: "i work",
   tag: "i work too"
}

function test({tag}){
   console.log(tag);
}

function test2(tag){
   console.log(tag);
}

test(obj)
test2(obj);
```